# Recover data from destroyed ZFS filesystem

Tags: data-recovery, zfs

I have a 1TB filesystem in a Proxmox environment, that was unluckily destroyed by Proxmox while trying to restore a container. Can the filesystem be recovered, or at least part of the data stored in it?

I have tried using zpool -Df, but returns an empty set, I guess thats because it is for pools and I am trying to restore a filesystem. 
Relevant logs from zpool history, original filesystem created in the first line.

```
2018-10-25.00:08:13 zfs create -o acltype=posixacl -o xattr=sa -o refquota=1048576000k hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
2019-06-30.21:18:28 zfs destroy -r hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
2019-06-30.21:19:10 zfs create -o acltype=posixacl -o xattr=sa -o refquota=10485760k hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
2019-06-30.21:20:03 zfs destroy -r hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
2019-06-30.21:23:26 zfs create -o acltype=posixacl -o xattr=sa -o refquota=10485760k hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
2019-06-30.21:24:08 zfs destroy -r hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
2019-07-01.00:25:15 zfs create -o acltype=posixacl -o xattr=sa -o refquota=10485760k hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
2019-07-01.00:26:27 zfs destroy -r hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
2019-07-01.01:00:10 zfs create -o acltype=posixacl -o xattr=sa -o refquota=10485760k hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
2019-07-01.01:00:29 zfs destroy -r hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
2019-07-01.01:16:08 zfs create -o acltype=posixacl -o xattr=sa -o refquota=10485760k hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
2019-07-01.01:16:27 zfs destroy -r hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
2019-07-01.01:19:18 zfs create -o acltype=posixacl -o xattr=sa -o refquota=10485760k hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
2019-07-01.01:19:36 zfs destroy -r hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
2019-07-01.01:23:05 zfs create -o acltype=posixacl -o xattr=sa -o refquota=10485760k hddp/subvol-100-disk-0
```

Could any file stored within the old filesystem be recovered?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, most likely the answer is no, you cannot meaningfully recover the data that was in the file system that was destroyed on 2019-06-30.21:18:28. The fact that a new file system with the same dataset name has been subsequently created does not really factor into this.

As a general rule of thumb, in ZFS, absent backups, `zfs destroy` is irreversible, but `zpool destroy` is reversible as long as the überblocks haven't been overwritten.